Which 'flavour' of make is installed as part of xcode on Mac OSX?
I'm trying to create a makefile that will work on OSX, but I don't know what style of conditional statement to use.  (I don't have access to a Mac).
Does the version of make installed with xcode on OSX use conditional statements like ifeq ($(OS), Darwin) or does it use conditional statements like .if ${OS} == "Darwin"?
Have all versions of xcode always used the same flavour of make or has it changed in more recent versions?
Thank you

MacOS provides a very old version of GNU Make (GNU Make 3.81) by default.  GNU Make uses ifeq etc. not .if.

Thank you - do you want o post that as the answer?

You can detect the type of make by running it with various options; if it's GNU Make (uses ifeq) then the make --version and/or make --help options will show information about the version as well as some copyright information that will make this clear.
I'm not familiar with the BSD versions of make (uses .if) but if --version doesn't work maybe -v or similar will.
MacOS ships a very old version of GNU Make (GNU Make 3.81, released in April 2006, so over 18 years old now) as their "default" version of GNU Make.

Of course if you don't have access to a MacOS system the information on options won't help you :)
